# How to give input Mapreduce jobs which use s3 data from java code

Tags: input, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, mapreduce

I know that we can normally give the parameters while running the jar file in EC2 instance

But how do we give inputs through code?
I am trying this because I am trying to call my java code from a jsp, so in the java code ,I want to directly pick up data from s3 and proceed , I tries like this but in vain:

```
DataExtractor.getRelevantData("s3n://syamk/revanthinput/", "999999", "94645", "20120606",
             "s3n://revanthufl/gen/testoutput" + "interm");
```

here `s3n://syamk/revanthinput/` I was using input and instead of `s3n://revanthufl/gen/testoutput`.
I was using output and in the parameters I am using the same strings(`s3n://syamk/revanthinput/` and `s3n://revanthufl/gen/testoutput`) to run the jar.But doing like this from code is throwing and exception,

> [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).] with root cause

Answer (score 0):

Based on my usage of flume, it would appear that you need to format your URL like `s3n://AWS_ACCESS_KEY:AWS_SECRET_KEY@syamk/revanthinput/` when calling s3 from within code.